# Yammer embedded customize font size

Tags: javascript, yammer

Is it possible to change the zoom or the font-size used by Yammer Embed? I was trying to access to the element created by the yammer iframe, but cannot.
After the iframe is loaded I can adjust the HTML zoom or font-size from the console. Is there JavaScript that you can suggest?

This code on the console works, but fails from inside the page:

```
 $('.yj-thread-list--content').css('zoom','85%');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the internal styling of Yammer Embed is unsupported. You should not attempt to do this because you'll run into problems getting support for other issues, or create additional problems from your code failing to run. It may be a good idea to submit a request for this capability through the [Yammer UserVoice](https://yammer.uservoice.com/) site.

Comment: Thank you. The idea is to be able to improve the view embedded with the context of our application. I'll submit a request!